# FTP - failed to open file

Tags: ftp

I'm trying to copy a website using the ftp connection. Some files fail to arive to my computer. They seems to exist on the server but i can't copy them. It is about some html and php files. When I try to read them i get a '550 failed to open file error'. Same 550 error appears when i try to delete it using my ftp connection.

The real problem is not about the fact that I can't copy those files. The problem is that an antivirus consider my website as infected and blocks the acces to it. I've copyied the same website to another server and it is not blocked. Also, when the website runs from my localhost server, the antivirus doesn't report any problem.  Other websites from that server don't have this problem. The only difference is those files that I can't copy or view.

Do you have any advice for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 550 error code should only come from the remote FTP server - It is a "Permission Denied" message saying you can't access the *remote* file.
While it's possible your antivirus is sitting in the middle of your FTP session and blocking your access I'm not sure how likely that is.

If you are ***certain*** you aren't trying to download something that will infect your system, and you suspect your antivirus software is the problem **disable the AV software and try again**.  One of two things will happen:

1. The problem will go away.
   This means your antivirus software is overzealous.  I suggest replacing it with AV software that doesn't interfere with normal tasks.
2. The problem will not go away.
   This means you have a more mundane problem of bad permissions on the remote end of the connection.  Fix the permissions, or contact the administrator of the remote system and ask them to do so.

Comment: can be a hdd problem on the server side, as it happens under windows and needs a checkdisk? what do I have to ask to the sys admin?

Answer (score -2):

I put " " around the filename and it worked. Permissions were the same but some spaces in file name and it not like ' ' (single quotes)

Comment: I suggest to be more concret. Why it works?